# How to fix CA2225 (OperatorOverloadsHaveNamedAlternates) when using generic class

Tags: c#, .net, generics, code-analysis, implicit-conversion

I'm trying to resolve [CA2225](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms182355.aspx), which WARNs on `ContrainedValue<T>` below, with the following message: `Provide a method named 'ToXXX' or 'FromXXX' as an alternate for operator 'ConstrainedValue<T>.implicit operator T(ConstrainedValue<T>)'.`

I've also pasted `PositiveInteger` to illustrate a use-case for `ConstrainedValue<T>`.  `ConstrainedValue<T>` enables derivatives to simply specify the constraint being applied to a value type, in the constructor.  It seems like a pretty clean way to code this up.  Is there any way to resolve the  CA2225 warning, given that I'm dealing with a generic type?  How can I provide an alternate operator?

- Perhaps I could implement `ToInt`, `ToDouble`, etc. for all value types and have them throw if the `from` is not of the same type?  But I think it's a bad practice to have the ToXXX method throw?
- I could create a layer in-between `ConstrainedValue<T>` and `PositiveInteger<T>`, a `ConstrainedInteger` class.  I could put `ToInt()` in that class.  But it seems wrong to create a layer simply to satisfy CA2225 and I don't think the warning would go away on `ConstrainedValue<T>` and I would have to suppress that warning.

Code:

```
namespace OBeautifulCode.AutoFakeItEasy
 {
    using System.Diagnostics;

    using Conditions;

    /// <summary>
    /// Represents a constrained value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the constrained value.</typeparam>
    [DebuggerDisplay("{Value}")]
    public abstract class ConstrainedValue<T>
        where T : struct
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ConstrainedValue{T}"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">The value of the <see cref="ConstrainedValue{T}"/> instance.</param>
        protected ConstrainedValue(T value)
        {
            this.Value = value;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the underlying value of the instance.
        /// </summary>
        public T Value { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Performs an implicit conversion from <see cref="ConstrainedValue{T}"/> to the underlying value type.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="from">The <see cref="ConstrainedValue{T}"/> to convert from.</param>
        /// <returns>
        /// The result of the conversion.
        /// </returns>
        public static implicit operator T(ConstrainedValue<T> from)
        {
            return from.Value;
        }            
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Represents a positive integer.
    /// </summary>
    [DebuggerDisplay("{Value}")]
    public sealed class PositiveInteger : ConstrainedValue<int>
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="PositiveInteger"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">The value held by the <see cref="PositiveInteger"/> instance.</param>
        public PositiveInteger(int value)
            : base(value)
        {
            Condition.Requires(value, nameof(value)).IsGreaterThan(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the code analysis happy by actually doing what it says:

Insert this in `ConstrainedValue<T>` and the warning will go away.

```
public T ToT()
{
  return this.Value;
}
```

Personally, I'd rather suppress the message, you already provide a method to get the value even if the language does not provide casting.

Comment: Weird...I actually tried this and the warning remained, but a re-start of VS and a rebuild fixed it up!  Anyways, I think suppressing the warning is certainly better than `ToT()`, which is likely to be confusing to an end-user.  Thanks for the answer!  Will keep question open for other ideas. I would like to provide legible alternate operators like ToInt, ToDouble, etc. because it seems like a good practice, but not sure what the best way is to implement that.  Maybe it really doesn't matter.

Comment: I suppose I could implement `ToT()`, create a `ConstrainedInteger` that derives from `ConstrainedValue` and implement a `ToInt` which simply callls `ToT()` and then have `PositiveInteger` derive from `ConstrainedInteger`

Comment: Actually, the answered approach doesn't fully work.  It generates `CA1000 - Do not declare static members on generic types`.  LOL!

Comment: @SFun28 For me it doesn't. It's not even static.

Comment: right.  I was implementing it as `public static T ToT(ConstrainedValue<T> from)`  Does it matter whether it's static or not to satisfy the CLS concern?  I just assumed it should be static because the implicit operator is static.  The example in MSDN uses a static method.

Comment: @SFun28 You can trivially test it yourself. Yes, the method I posted, copy&pasted into your class will work.

Comment: yes, I am agreeing that it works to get rid of the warning.  What I'm asking about is whether we just tricked the compiler or whether this is the proper implementation for the CLS concern as stated in MSDN `"Most languages do not support operator overloading. For this reason, it is a CLS requirement for all types that overload operators to include a secondary method with an appropriate domain-specific name that provides the equivalent functionality"`.  I suppose it doesn't state anything about static.  While static is more broadly usable, the instance method will work?! so maybe it's just fine

Comment: To make it CLR compliant, you already provide a method called `get_Value()` that people with neither operator overloading nor properties in their .NET language can call. The only problem is that the automatic checking tool cannot know the logic of your program and therefor cannot tell that this is the case.

Comment: Much appreciated!  Thanks for clarifying!